# golang open Downloads folder explorer window on Windows 10 not working

Tags: go, windows-explorer

I can open a explorer window using on Windows 10 cmd

```sh
explorer C:\Users\bruce\Downloads\
```

So I'm thinking executing this command in go, but it opens `Documents` folder instead of `Downloads` folder, how can I solve this issue

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "runtime"
)

func main() {
    homeDir, _ := os.UserHomeDir()

    if runtime.GOOS == "darwin" {
        downloadDir := homeDir + "/Downloads/"
        cmd := `open "` + downloadDir + `"`
        exec.Command("/bin/bash", "-c", cmd).Output()
    } else {
        downloadDir := homeDir + "\\Downloads\\"
        cmd := `explorer ` + downloadDir
        fmt.Println("cmd: ", cmd)
        exec.Command("cmd", "/C", cmd).Output()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved, turns out that the first parameter of `exec.Command()` should use `explorer` instead of `cmd`

The snippet below is working

```golang
package main

import (
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "runtime"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    homeDir, _ := os.UserHomeDir()
    downloadDir := homeDir + "/Downloads/"
    if runtime.GOOS == "darwin" {
        cmd := `open "` + downloadDir + `"`
        exec.Command("/bin/bash", "-c", cmd).Start()
    } else {
        downloadDir = strings.ReplaceAll(downloadDir, "/", "\\")
        exec.Command("explorer", downloadDir).Start()
    }
}
```

**Edit**

More simplified version, use `downloadDir := filepath.Join(homeDir, "Downloads")` instead of `downloadDir = strings.ReplaceAll(downloadDir, "/", "\\")`

```golang
package main

import (
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "path/filepath"
    "runtime"
)

func main() {
    homeDir, _ := os.UserHomeDir()
    downloadDir := filepath.Join(homeDir, "Downloads")
    if runtime.GOOS == "darwin" {
        exec.Command("open", downloadDir).Start()
    } else {
        exec.Command("explorer", downloadDir).Start()
    }
}
```

**Edit2**

```golang
package main

import (
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "path/filepath"
    "runtime"
)

func main() {
    homeDir, _ := os.UserHomeDir()
    downloadDir := filepath.Join(homeDir, "Downloads")
    cmd := "open"
    if runtime.GOOS == "windows" {
        cmd = "explorer"
    }
    exec.Command(cmd, downloadDir).Start()
}
```

**Edit3**

According to @panapol-p point out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70809805/7807426)

```golang
package main

import (
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "path/filepath"
    "runtime"
)

func main() {
    homeDir, _ := os.UserHomeDir()

    cmd := "open"
    downloadDir := filepath.Join(homeDir, "Downloads")
    if runtime.GOOS == "windows" {
        cmd = "explorer"
        downloadDir = "shell:downloads"
    }
    exec.Command(cmd, downloadDir).Start()
}
```

Comment: You should probably also use `filepath.Join()` instead of replacing the "/" with "\\" manually. Like: `downloadDir := filepath.Join(homeDir, "Downloads")`

Comment: @Bazzz Oh, thank you for reminding, I'm a newbie on golang.

Comment: The if-statement is also a little flaky now. Perhaps this is better: `cmd := "open" if runtime.GOOS == "windows" { cmd = "explorer" } exec.Command(cmd, downloadDir).Start()` I would reckon that you figured that only Windows needs `explorer` so your if statement should represent that finding. Now it says that only Mac needs `open` and all the others need `explorer`, which I think is not true.

Comment: @Bazzz Exactly, thank you so much!

Comment: This will only work if the Windows system it runs on is installed in English and then only if the user hasn't moved or renamed the Downloads directory.

Answer (score 0):

**[for window]**
I recommend using a specific folder instead of joining the path by yourself,
because when you install the application on a custom download path, your application will be run with the wrong condition.

a specific folder is a standard folder that was registered with the system and this one is on XP or higher version of window

for manual, you can use like this

> win + r -> shell:{specific folder}

example

> win + r -> shell:downloads

for golang you can use like this

```
err := exec.Command("explorer", "shell:downloads").Start()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalln(err.Error())
}
```

for more information
https://gist.github.com/gabe31415/ac22a4f5c874ee33ab0083fdb4e24e66

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the potential the issue, I'll use your solution.

Comment: but there is another problem, my program is to save files to the download folder, I join that path too, it seems I need to get the "real download folder" path instead of joining, but it seems complicated, need to use Powershell?

Comment: I found this repo [gowin](https://github.com/luisiturrios1/gowin) , you can get real path from window register.